# Sending bits on a coaxial cable

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics

When you are sending bits or voltage's through a coaxial cable from 1 PC to another PC, does current flow from PC1 to PC2 through the cable?
If so, mustn't there be a complete circuit?

Comment: hence twisted pairs, or coaxial cables, are used.

Comment: Why do you think there is not a complete circuit? You're aware that coax has two conductors, right? Shield and center conductor? The shield is not called a conductor (the term is reserved for the center), but do you really think the shield is an insulator?

Comment: you cannot have current flow without a complete circuit ..... you seem to know that already ..... what are you really asking? .... it seems that what you asked is not really what you want to ask

Answer (score 3):

The 'coaxial' part of the name 'coaxial cable' refers to the fact that there are **two** conductors arranged around the same axis -- there's an inner wire, and an outer shield.  Both carry current.

In a correctly designed system, the shield carries a current equal and opposite to the center conductor.

Comment: If it was possible to upvote +100 for the last sentence of your answer it would already be done.

Comment: So essentially, the complete circuit involving both PC1 and 2 comes from the wires within the coaxial cable

Comment: "So essentially, the complete circuit ..."  Correct, although the outer conductor (or the inner, for that matter) isn't necessarily a wire.  Hardline is a (usually) wire inside of a tube.  If the outer shield isn't at least braided into a tubular conductor, however flexible, then it doesn't deserve the name coax.

Comment: @MichaelKaras because it's true, or because systems in the field don't always manage it? :)

Comment: Coaxial means the 2 conductors, the outer and inner, **co**-exist or share the same **axial** path, regardless of construction; braid, foil, semi-rigid,hardline or whatever. The ratio between the conductors and inner wire radius changes for 50 to 75 OHms due to L/C ratio